# Extract data from forum

Tags: php, forum, vbulletin

İ want to extract data from a php forum based on keywords I entered.
İs there something ready that can do this?
Just to give example
[Kadinlarkulubu.com/forum.php](http://Kadinlarkulubu.com/forum.php)
Keywords ios, android

Thanks to this info I want to get date, time, message, URL of message, keyword in the message, nick of member who wrote this message.

I need to work in different forums, so I need one or more tools that will work on key big platforms like vBulletin.

Comment: I assume the answer is no, but just to make sure: do you have access to the forum's database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own [web crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler). If you want it to work on various different platforms, you will have to create variations on that crawler.

To start, picks your favourite forum, and give it a seed page (the page where to start crawling). Tread carefully, since you may need to be logged in to be able to see posts, and if that's the case, it may not be easy to do (making a crawler that logs you in, and breaks the captcha, for example). You can also make use of the search functionality (since many forums have search URLs similar to `?q=your_tag&p=1`, this could make things a lot easier.

Just check that you're on the same domain, and that you don't go into an infinite loop, other than that, you should be fine.

Expect this to be a long term project :)

The alternative would be using API, if the forum provides one, but I doubt you will be so lucky.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways
The easy way is only possible if the owner of the forum provides you access to the forum API (if it has one) or the database

The extreme hard way is make a grabber that reads a forum page by page and parses the information you like to something you can use.